# idiomatic way to align Select fields with TextInput fields?

Tags: material-ui

ok, when running v1.x (currently beta) i ran into a predicament with `TextField` and `Select` fields not lining up consistently in a horizontal layout (see below). 
[image]

i read over [the demo](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/demos/selects/), didn't spot a solution, spent more time than i care to admit unfruitfully experimenting in chrome dev-tools, and not being entirely confident with my css skills, decided to post this question here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i want to thank whoever down-voted my question because it made me regroup and look with fresh (or perhaps less bleary) eyes. often times, as was the case here, i overlooked [occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) and move too quickly past more obvious solutions. the trick here was the container styles spelled out in [the demo](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/demos/selects/):

```
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
```

and boom:

[image]